# Testing full program by comparing output file to reference file: what's it called, and is there a package for it?

Tags: python, testing

I have a completely non-interactive python program that takes some command-line options and input files and produces output files.  It can be fairly easily tested by choosing simple cases and writing the input and expected output files by hand, then running the program on the input files and comparing output files to the expected ones.

1) What's the name for this type of testing?

2) Is there a python package to do this type of testing? 
It's not difficult to set up by hand in the most basic form, and I did that already. But then I ran into cases like output files containing the date and other information that can legitimately change between the runs - I considered writing something that would let me specify which sections of the reference files should be allowed to be different and still have the test pass, and realized I might be getting into "reinventing the wheel" territory. 
(I rewrote a good part of unittest functionality before I caught myself last time this happened...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're referring to a form of [system testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_testing).

No package would know which parts can legitimately change.  My suggestion is to mock out the sections of code that result in the changes so that you can be sure that the output is always the same - you can use tools like [Mock](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) for that.  Comparing two files is pretty straightforward, just dump each to a string and compare strings.

Comment: Though it might just be simpler to structure your validation files as sequences of regexes and then validate that each line matches the expected regex in this case.

Comment: Yes, no package would know which parts of the output can legitimately change, but it could have a syntax that would allow me to put markers in some sections of the reference output file to tell it to ignore any differences in those sections - that's basically what I was thinking of writing, but I may be missing some reason why it would be difficult and/or a bad idea.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see your comment when I wrote mine. Yes, that's a good idea. Do you know if there's an existing tool to do this kind of regex-based file comparison? (Again, not difficult to write by myself, I'm just trying to avoid reinventing existing things.)

Comment: You could do that, but making the output repeatable is what unit testing is all about.  Doing it this way will also result is some fairly complicated tests, which is always a bad idea because then you need to test the tests.

Comment: Also, yes, system testing sounds right, thanks!  And I'll take a look at Mock - that sounds interesting.  (I get the feeling I'm writing too many comments.)

Comment: Well, there's no guarantee this is strictly unit testing.  It's valid to test in a real world environment as well, you are just getting closer to integration tests then.

Comment: I did end up writing the regex thing... The tests aren't very complicated, I'm really only using the regexes to skip some output that's unlikely to be wrong (date/etc). You're right that mocking is probably the right way to do this - I should read up on it at some point, but for now this will do. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Functional testing.  Or regression testing, if that is its purpose.  Or code coverage, if you structure your data to cover all code paths.

Comment: After some googling I'm still unclear on the difference between functional testing and system testing, but what I'm doing is probably both - thanks for the new term.

Comment: Who downvotes a legitimate answer to an explicitly stated question?  In any case, the name for the type of testing has as much to do with where in the product workflow it is used as it does what it actually does.

Comment: @sr2222: I did not downvote. In general, I believe that it is recommended protocol to accompany a downvote with an explanation. In that way the downvote can be taken as constructive criticism.  If no explanation is given, it could be that you angered someone and they wish to exact some revenge. The site maintainers say the system will catch such "revenge-voting" and reverse it. If it doesn't, I'm sure you can post about it on meta if you would like someone to undertake an investigation.

Comment: @bernie meh.  Not that important.